# Django-admin module name not found?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django version 1.6.11 and when I want to create the project by using the command `Django-admin start project my site` it throws the error:

> \Python27\python.exe: No module named Django-admin

and when I use `Django-admin.py start project my site` it opens a new file named Django-admin.py.

I don't know what the issue is as when I open an already created Django project I am able to run the project using `python manage.py run server` but then also I am not able to create new app inside the project as it requires `Django-admin startapp`.

Comment: First, you can use `python manage.py startapp <app>` to start a new project. Are you sure you are trying to run `django-admin` from the command line and *not* within the Python REPL?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the right command to start a project?
According to official documentation, it should be:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

not

```
Django-admin start project my site
```

Which means: no uppercase and less spaces.
New apps should be created using:

```
python manage.py startapp app_name_here
```

not through django-admin.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/